# Count down timer taking time in start

Tags: javascript

I write a java script function to show a count down. But somehow when i start this timer it take 3-4 sec delay and then show count down on html. Can someone tell me why it taking this delay in start.

```js
var seconds = 30;
var timer;

function myFunction() {
  if (seconds < 30) {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "You are block for " + seconds + " second";
  }
  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
if (!timer) {
  timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    myFunction();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
delay
The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should delay in between executions of the specified function or code. If this parameter is less than 10, a value of 10 is used. Note that the actual delay may be longer; see "Reasons for delays longer than specified" in WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout() for examples.

Comment: You should change block to blocked

Comment: And change <30 to <=30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two reasons :

1. setInterval doesn't start immediately, you need to call the function once before the setInterval.
2. and, you are not showing the 30th second, so you just made one second delay.

```js
var seconds = 30;
var timer;

function myFunction() {
  if (seconds <= 30) { // changed to <= 30
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "You are block for " + seconds + " second";
  }
  if (seconds > 0) {
seconds--;
  } else {
clearInterval(timer);
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
if (!timer) {
  myFunction(); // call it once before setInterval
  timer = window.setInterval(function() {
     myFunction();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I also fixed some spelling for you and knowing me probably screwed it up:

```
function myFunction () {
//changed to be <= instead of just <
if ( seconds <= 30 ) { 
document . getElementById ( "countdown" ). innerHTML = "You are blocked for " + seconds + " seconds" ; } if ( seconds > 0 ) { 
seconds --; } else { 
clearInterval ( timer ); 
document . getElementById ( "countdown" ). innerHTML = "" ; } } if (! timer ) { 
timer = window . setInterval ( function () { 
myFunction (); }, 1000 ); 
//call function immediately as well as every second afterwards
myFunction() }
```